# python 3 - search a text file -

Tags: python-3.x

I am having problems with my code. I want to search for a string in the a comma delimited text file.

Each line in the file is a record with 8 fields, separated by commas. On this exercise I like to search only the first field.

The "myfile.txt" looks like this:

```
joe,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,00005
john,bush,Avenue George V,paris,Halifax,canada,00006
denise,Hoche,Avenue George V,paris,Greater Paris,france,00007
```

I am only able to find text on the 1st line:

> search for text: joe
>   ['joe','smith', '111 jorge st', 'autin', 'texas', 'usa', '00005\n']

If i search for for text in the 2nd line, it returns no result

> search for text: denise
>   cannot find the text

```
while True:
search = input ('search for text: ')
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if search in line:
            text1, test2, text3, text4, text4, text5, text6,text7 = line.split(',')
            print (text1)
            break
        print ('cannot find the text')
        break
```

Please let me know what is wrong. Thank you

Comment: Have you read your code?

Comment: When you do you want the code to print the `'can find'` message? It's not at all obvious from your code or the message text's psuedo-english what you really want it to do.

Comment: i change to "cannot find the text". Thank you for point out the misspelling

Comment: Couple of questions. Do you want to print all matches? Do you want to allow partial matches for each item (delimited by comma) or whole word matches including or excluding matching case?

Answer (score -1):

Check this if it helps you.

```
    file=open(file="hello.txt",encoding='utf-8',mode='r')
    counter=1
    #Put your search key here use input()
    search="joe"
    def mole(search,collector,counter):
        #This will search for keyword from collector which is a list type
        for elem in collector:
            if search==elem:
                print("Matched")
                print("Line no :",counter)
                break
            else:
                pass

    for lines in file:
        if lines=='\n':
            print("EOF..")
            break
            collector=lines.split(",")
            #To strip "\n" from lines in file
            collector[6]=collector[6].strip('\n')
            mole(search,collector,counter)
            counter+=1
    file.flush()
    file.close()
    print("Search complete..")


hello.txt----

joe,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,05
jhhfghg,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,02
jhhfghg,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,03
jhhfghg,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,00006fdg
jhhfghg,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,00006fgdf
jhhfghg,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,0000fdg6
jhhfghg,smith,111 jorge st,autin,texas,usa,0000fgf
```

Comment: My question was relate with my code. 

I am searching the entire file but ONLY returns result if the record exist on the 1st line.

Comment: an explanation could go the distance

Comment: @beginningpython I did look at your code and made some changes to mine so it works fine!